# How do I configure a upload folder in IIS6 and asp.net? win server 2003 sp2

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, permissions, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have an internal asp.net app that uses the fileupload control to put data files in a "drop" folder. I would like to lock down this folder so only users that are part of a local group can actually authenticate and upload the file. 
I have created a group on the server, added the domain users to the local group. I have then given that group write access to the "drop" directory.

When I try to upload a file to the directory I get the expected login screeen but my login doesn't work and after several tries the page errors out with "**Access to path '\server\path\fubar\drop folder name\filename.txt" is denied**"

How do I set it up so that each user has to login but the login actually works?
TIA
J

Comment: This is more of a server config question.  Should be migrated to serverfault.com

Comment: It is but then this is to do with ASP.net secuity the two work hand in hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a permission issue.

1) You need to set up impersonation on the IIS webserver (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc.aspx). This will allow the network credentials to be passed through from any internet explorer browser to the web server.

2) You then need to right click on the upload folder and then go to 'properties' --> 'security' --> 'edit' --> 'add' --> type in the name of the users/groups --> click ok --> select correct privaliges (Read and Modify).

NOTE: if you are operating a an internal web application you dont need the user to log in. Thats the whole point of impersonation. No point in makign people log in if they have authenticated on the network already.

If you must make them log in over the top then you need to validate them against your AD server and then change the user that the page is operting under programatically like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.User.Identity = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    }
```

Comment: I walked through the article referenced in #1 and then applied step #2. I don't particularly need the login prompt, and in fact would prefer for it to not show up.  I still get the prompt for login and my non-domain admin account still gives the error. As before if I use a domain admin account it works correctly.

Comment: The first thing to do is get the credentials being passed from IE to the application. I would start by setting a page up and writing the this.user.Identity out to the screen. Then try from different machines and see if the web server is picking up and passing the correct details through to .net. Then look into the further issue.

Comment: Have a look this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx, get the site picking up the impersonation then look at your other issues seperately. Just break the problem down. It is possible you just have to do it one step at a a time.